# multiply diagonal values of a matrix in java

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, multidimensional-array, int

I want to multiply 2 diagonals of a Matrix. But i am not able to get the diagonals of matrix. like in given code two diagonals are `d1=5*5*9`. and `d2=3*5*7` then i will use **d1** and **d2** values for further process.

How to do it. 
Note: matrix size can be different like here its **3x3** but it can be **5x5**

```
private static int diagonalMultiply(int [][]arr1){
    int[][]  arr= {
       {5,2,3},
       {4,5,6},    
       {7,8,9}
   };
for ( int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) //stepping along the x axis again.
{
    for ( int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) // stepping along the y axis.
    {
        System.out.print(arr[x][y]+" ");
    }    
}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A diagonal of an N×N matrix has N elements. A pair of nested loops, each going from `0` to `N-1`, cover N<sup>2</sup> elements. This means that you need one loop, not two.

Both diagonals can be retrieved in a single loop. Indexes of the descending diagonal are `(i, i)`, while indexes of the ascending one are `(N-i-1, i)`:

```
int N = arr.length;
for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i][i]+" "+arr[N-i-1][i]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/yxRUHz)